# How to bind my xml data to a listbox?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I want to bind my Data from xml file to a listbox but i fail.

Here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cams>
   <Cam>
     <Name>Name</Name>
     <Link>Link</Link>
     <Path>Path</Path>
   </Cam>
</Cams>
```

And here the begin of my Xaml file :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:CamManager.Properties" x:Name="MainForm" x:Class="CamManager.MainWindow"
    Title="CamManager" Height="190.69" Width="336.724" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" Source="CamCollection.xml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="322" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="519">
        <TabItem Header="Collection">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,0,185,153">
                <ListBox x:Name="Collection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Cams/Cam/Name}"/>
                <Button x:Name="Launch" Content="Launch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.103,-0.084"/>
                <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

And When i start the program my listbox stay empty, so i would like there is "Name".

Edit : Thanks for your solution but that was not my problem, i dont know why but i have to specify the entire path to my xml when i specify the source

Source="C:\Users...\CamCollection.xml"
If you know why ?

Comment: What happens if you change `CamCollection` in your `XPath` to just `Cams`? You don't have a `CamCollection` in your xml.

Comment: Yes that a cause of my problem but not all

Answer (score 2):

solution1:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" Source="CamCollection.xml" XPath="Cams/Cam/Name"/>
```

solution2:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Collection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=Cams/Cam/Name}"/>
```